# My program for getting the average doesn't quite work

Tags: python

```
def opdracht3()
a = True
result = 0
waslijst = []
while a:
    n = input("Enter a number: ")
    if n == "stop":
        a = False
    else:
        waslijst += n
for nummer in waslijst:
    result += int(nummer)
eind = result / len(waslijst)
print(eind)
opdracht3()
```

I want to get the average of the list that is being created, but when I add numbers like 11, the len(waslijst) gets set to 2 instead of 1. Is there another way to get the average, or am I using the len function wrong?

Comment: Use `waslijst.append(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `.append` method to store all elements in a list.

```
def opdracht3():
    a = True
    result = 0
    waslijst = []
    while a:
       n = input("Enter a number: ")
       if n == "stop":
          a = False
       else:
          waslijst.append(n)
    for nummer in waslijst:
       result += int(nummer)
    eind = result / len(waslijst)
    print(eind)
opdracht3()
```